# CRM 2016 On premise - Can not connect to CRM with Plugin Registration In IFD Mode

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm-2015, dynamics-crm-2016, ifd, xrmtoolbox

I have Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2016 On Premise and IFD Enabled On it.
In this situation I can not connect plugin Registration to CRM. Even I can not connect with XRMtoolbox.
My problem is what is Home Realm URL?

> Unable to Login to Dynamics CRM

[image]

> An Error occurred while processing the login request.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem is In adfs Endpoints. After you Install IFD on CRM You want a Important Endpoint That Named "Mex".

For Solve The Problem First go to ADFS Management and go to endpoints and Click on adfs/services/trust/Mex and click on Enable and Enable on proxy for this Endpoint. after that reset the iis and adfs service. 
Then You can Browse that enpoint with https://service.contoso.com/adfs/services/trust/mex.
if you See the Metadata Xml Document Now You Can Connect With Any Tool Like Portal, Plugin Registration, Xrmtoolbox, etc.
but If you Don't see this metadata use this Command in Power shell to Change The Adfs Port.

```
Set-ADFSProperties –nettcpport: 809
```

i Choose 809 for My Port And You Can choose any port you want Except 443 or 80 or 90, Then like before Restart The IIS and Restart ADFS Service and then you Can see metadata And You Can Connect With Any Application to CRM 2016 On Premise IFD Mode.

At The End Of this Answer You can See My Metadata Page And My Connected Plugin Registration Tool Pictures.

If You Have Any Question You Can Ask it From Me.

[image: This Is My Server]
[image: My Plugin Registration is Connected]

Answer (score 1):

Try removing all your 3rd party plugins except the plugging registration tool.

Also there is a plugin registration tool from Microsoft in the CRM SDK download that you can use as well.

Answer (score 1):

Do yourself a favor and download the [CRM 2011 SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24004).  In the bin folder is the plug-in registration tool.  The new version released in 2013+ is complete garbage with bugs that Microsoft Support is not interested in fixing.

That said, I don't think you can "Use Default Credentials" with IFD.  For the server you should just put organizationName.domainname.tld.  For user name use your UPN or domain\username.  Don't use both the domain and user name fields unless you're using integrated authentication.